# Creating a Dataset Class in PyTorch From a Set of .mat Files

Tags: pytorch, mat, pytorch-dataloader

I am working on a LIDAR problem where I am trying to map a set of 3D Histogram measurements (size [64,64,128]) to an original depth map (size [64,64]). I have a folder full of .mat files, each with their own measurement of the recorded histogram and ground truth depth.

In the example picture I have the .mat file of an example measurement. All that matters for now is SPAD and depth.

Example `.mat` File:
[image]

I would like to create a Dataset class in PyTorch that has a SPAD measurement, but am stuck on how to do so given the folder.

You can read `.mat` files in PyTorch using:

```py
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/LIDAR/SPAD_NYU/SPAD_Counts/spad_measurements_dining_room_0001a_0051.mat')
spad = mat['spad']
depth = mat['depth']
```

And I know you can create a custom Dataset using:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, IterableDataset, Dataloader
class CTSet(Dataset):
  def __init__(self):
    
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataset)
  def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.dataset[idx],self.labels[idx]
```

Followed by using Dataloader to train. I have the folder, SPAD_Counts, mounted to Drive in Google Colab. I would like to:

1. Loop through the folder
2. For each .mat file, get the spad and depth file.
3. Convert these, which are np arrays, to Torch Tensors. (Assumedly I do this in init)
4. Return a particular measurement's spad and depth in a way that is workable for iterating when I am training with Dataloader (Assumedly done in getitem)

I have looked at other implementations of custom datasets, however they are all using CSV files that make the process easier. If I can't make a CSV file for this kind of info, since it's a 3D array mapped to a 2D array, what do I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you should write your own `Dataset` for these `.mat` files.
You can use [`os.listdir`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) to list all files in a subfolder. `torchvision` library has several very useful transformations/augmentations that you can use. Specifically, [`torchvision.transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html) that converts `np.array`s into `torch.tensors`.

Overall, your custom `Dataset` would look something like:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, IterableDataset, Dataloader

class CTSet(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, base_dir, transforms):
    super(CTSet, self).__init__()
    self.transforms = transforms  # make sure transforms has at leat ToTensor()
    self.data = []  # store all data here
    # go over all files in base_dir
    for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
      if file.endswith('.mat'):
        mat = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(base_dir, file))
        self.data.append((mat['spad'], mat['depth']))

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)

  def __getitem__(self,index):
    spad, depth = self.data[index]
    return self.transforms(spad), self.transform(depth)
```